# Detecting if a specific route/tunnel is used when reaching a website

Tags: linux, networking, ip, route

I need a way to detect if I'm visiting a website through a specific kernel route set by a VPN.

The reason being: sometimes I forget my company's VPN on and I navigate to porn sites. I need to detect if the porn website's ip (let's assume 181.123.123.123, it has a fixed ip or a CIDR) is being resolved through my company's VPN tunnel (as I see it in `ip route show`, multiple `tun0` tunnels are present).

Any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ip route get 181.123.123.123` to see the next hop for this destination address, which would be either your VPN tunnel, or your LAN/WLAN.